Gaussian Process with 3D input why is the output flat?
I would like to get an approximated surface out of 3-dimensional data, namely X, Y coordinate and speed value. I thought of Gaussian Process as a successful methodology. I have applied the code seen in this page to my data: https://www.kaggle.com/code/mejbahahammad/gaussian-processes-for-machine-learning
First, I show thethe methods I have used, then, the data I am trying to approximate and the result.

The methods I have used:

import numpy as np 

def kernel(X1, X2, l=1.0, sigma_f=1.0):
    '''
    Isotropic squared exponential kernel. Computes 
    a covariance matrix from points in X1 and X2.
    
    Args:
        X1: Array of m points (m x d).
        X2: Array of n points (n x d).

    Returns:
        Covariance matrix (m x n).
    '''
    sqdist = np.sum(X1**2, 1).reshape(-1, 1) + np.sum(X2**2, 1) - 2 * np.dot(X1, X2.T)
    return sigma_f**2 * np.exp(-0.5 / l**2 * sqdist)
    
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def plot_gp_2D(gx, gy, mu, X_train, Y_train, title, i):
    ax = plt.gcf().add_subplot(1, 2, i, projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(gx, gy, mu.reshape(gx.shape), cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, alpha=0.2, antialiased=False)
    ax.scatter(X_train[:,0], X_train[:,1], Y_train, c=Y_train, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
    #ax.set_zlim(0,100)
    ax.set_title(title)
    
from numpy.linalg import inv

def posterior_predictive(X_s, X_train, Y_train, l=1.0, sigma_f=1.0, sigma_y=1e-8):
    '''
    Computes the suffifient statistics of the GP posterior predictive distribution 
    from m training data X_train and Y_train and n new inputs X_s.
    
    Args:
        X_s: New input locations (n x d).
        X_train: Training locations (m x d).
        Y_train: Training targets (m x 1).
        l: Kernel length parameter.
        sigma_f: Kernel vertical variation parameter.
        sigma_y: Noise parameter.
    
    Returns:
        Posterior mean vector (n x d) and covariance matrix (n x n).
    '''
    K = kernel(X_train, X_train, l, sigma_f) + sigma_y**2 * np.eye(len(X_train))
    K_s = kernel(X_train, X_s, l, sigma_f)
    K_ss = kernel(X_s, X_s, l, sigma_f) + 1e-8 * np.eye(len(X_s))
    K_inv = inv(K)
    
    # Equation (4)
    mu_s = K_s.T.dot(K_inv).dot(Y_train)

    # Equation (5)
    cov_s = K_ss - K_s.T.dot(K_inv).dot(K_s)
    
    return mu_s, cov_s
    
from numpy.linalg import cholesky, det, lstsq
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def nll_fn(X_train, Y_train, noise, naive=True):
    '''
    Returns a function that computes the negative log marginal
    likelihood for training data X_train and Y_train and given 
    noise level.
    
    Args:
        X_train: training locations (m x d).
        Y_train: training targets (m x 1).
        noise: known noise level of Y_train.
        naive: if True use a naive implementation of Eq. (7), if 
               False use a numerically more stable implementation. 
        
    Returns:
        Minimization objective.
    '''
    def nll_naive(theta):
        # Naive implementation of Eq. (7). Works well for the examples 
        # in this article but is numerically less stable compared to 
        # the implementation in nll_stable below.
        K = kernel(X_train, X_train, l=theta[0], sigma_f=theta[1]) + \
            noise**2 * np.eye(len(X_train))
        return 0.5 * np.log(det(K)) + \
               0.5 * Y_train.T.dot(inv(K).dot(Y_train)) + \
               0.5 * len(X_train) * np.log(2*np.pi)

    def nll_stable(theta):
        # Numerically more stable implementation of Eq. (7) as described
        # in http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf, Section
        # 2.2, Algorithm 2.1.
        K = kernel(X_train, X_train, l=theta[0], sigma_f=theta[1]) + \
            noise**2 * np.eye(len(X_train))
        L = cholesky(K)
        return np.sum(np.log(np.diagonal(L))) + \
               0.5 * Y_train.T.dot(lstsq(L.T, lstsq(L, Y_train)[0])[0]) + \
               0.5 * len(X_train) * np.log(2*np.pi)
    
    if naive:
        return nll_naive
    else:
        return nll_stable


The data I am trying to approximate:
They are data out from a simulation, so they are not generate following any explicit function.

X_train_complete = pd.read_csv('X_train_speed.csv', header=None)
X_train_complete = pd.DataFrame(X_train_complete)
X_2D_train = X_train_complete[[0,1]].values

Y_2D_train = X_train_complete[2].values
tot_vehicles = len(X_2D_train)

Btw, I have made the X and Y coordinate 0-mean:
X_before_0mean = X_2D_train[:,0]
avg_X = np.mean(X_before_0mean)

Y_before_0mean = X_2D_train[:,1]
avg_Y = np.mean(Y_before_0mean)

X_after_0mean = np.ones(tot_vehicles)
Y_after_0mean = np.ones(tot_vehicles)

i=0
for i in range(tot_vehicles):
    X_after_0mean[i] = X_before_0mean[i]-avg_X    
    Y_after_0mean[i] = Y_before_0mean[i]-avg_Y

X_2D_train = np.column_stack((X_after_0mean,Y_after_0mean))

For the noise mentioned in the original code,
noise_2D = 0.01 

I have kept it even if my data should have a noise given by the documentation (error value: -2^30)

The meshgrid I have made:

x_min = np.min(x_start)
x_max = np.max(x_end)
y_min = np.min(y_start)
y_max = np.max(y_end)

factor=400
nBinsX =  int(x_max//factor)
nBinsY =  int(y_max//factor)
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, nBinsX)
y = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, nBinsY)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
XX = np.array([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).T
pos = np.dstack((X,Y))
X_2D = XX
X_2D = np.c_[X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]

Btw, I have made it 0-mean on the X and Y axis, modifying these two definitions:
x = np.linspace(x_min-(x_max+x_min)/2, x_max-(x_max+x_min)/2, nBinsX)
y = np.linspace(y_min-(x_max+x_min)/2, y_max-(x_max+x_min)/2, nBinsY)


The result:

mu_s, _ = posterior_predictive(X_2D, X_2D_train, Y_2D_train, sigma_y=noise_2D)

plt.figure(figsize=(14,7))
plot_gp_2D(X, Y, mu_s, X_2D_train, Y_2D_train, 
           f'Before parameter optimization: l={1.00} sigma_f={1.00}', 1)


# Parameters' optimization 
res = minimize(nll_fn(X_2D_train, Y_2D_train, noise_2D), [1, 1], 
               bounds=((1e-5, None), (1e-5, None)),
               method='L-BFGS-B')

mu_s, _ = posterior_predictive(X_2D, X_2D_train, Y_2D_train, *res.x, sigma_y=noise_2D)

plt.figure(figsize=(14,7))
plot_gp_2D(X, Y, mu_s, X_2D_train, Y_2D_train,
           f'After parameter optimization: l={res.x[0]:.2f} sigma_f={res.x[1]:.2f}', 1)


**Is there some parameters' value in the methods I should choose differently give the nature of the data I have? **
I have also tried

to change the factor value, so the size of the mesh
to sample a small number of the simulation points
But the approximation, the surface, is always flat

Thank you very much in advance for your attention.
